# Pandas, to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unit'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert unix time in pandas. I read this in from a csv file, but when I try to convert it, I get the above error.

```
#read the file in
df = pd.read_csv(files,parse_dates=True)

#create a new Data Frame with specific values from the original .csv
df2 = df[['timestamp','avg_hr','avg_rr','emfit_sleep_summary_id']]

#convert the timestamp to int
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].astype(int)

#convert time using, pd.to_datetime()
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'],unit='s')
print df2.head()
```

Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Emfit-Processing.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "Emfit-Processing.py", line 47, in main
    load_file()
  File "Emfit-Processing.py", line 31, in load_file
    df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'],unit='s')
TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unit'
```

Addtional info:

Pandas version is: 0.8.0

OS: Debian, installed using sudo apt-get install python-pandas (as per the official website)

**sample Data**

```
1422404668
1422404670
1422404672
1422404674
1422404676
1422404678
1422404680
1422404682
1422404684
1422404686
1422404688
1422404690
1422404692
```

Comment: What version pandas are you using? can you give an example value that reproduces this error

Comment: That's a very old version can you upgrade? The current latest stable version in `0.16.0` and this works fine

Comment: This version of pandas is 3 years old !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an old version, I cloned the new version from git and installed it. Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the result by simply passing the value to the parameter. I wonder what the keyword argument 'unit' is supposed to be doing there. check your pandas version.

```
pandas.to_datetime(1422404668)
```

Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:01.422404668')

I'm using pandas 0.15.2